# Wordpress Connection to Database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and it's fully functional in offline mode(localhost), but we need to transfer it now to another computer.

My problem is the `username` and `password` used in that Wordpress installation that I've created during the installation, how can I change it now?

What file should I edit, to properly connect to the database again?

Comment: [**wp-config.php**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

Comment: Thank you for the -1 and your answer. Being newbie is not that easy ..

Comment: It would take 3 seconds to search on google and understand what is the configuration file and how to modify it instead of asking here

Comment: Would you please refer this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress ? I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: I think this would anyways fit better to either DBA or Superuser as this has nothing to do with programming, does it?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Change your admin password using phpMyAdmin

You will look for the table `wp_users`, click on it and then click on the Browse Tab.

[image]

Click on the Pencil (Edit) Icon to reset your Password.

[image]

Now you will see a field that looks like this:

[image]

Edit the user_pass field value. You will notice that there are a lot of random characters in the password field. Due to security reasons, WordPress stores the passwords as [MD5 Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) rather than Plain text.

This means that you will not be able to enter plain text as the password. You would need to use one of the MD5 generators online to generate your password.

> #### Settings in wp-config.php File

Your WordPress database connection settings appear under ‘MySQL Settings’ section of the wp-config.php file. You will need your MySQL host, database name, database username and password to fill in this section.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the following step to do it..**

1. Export the database
2. Copy full project
3. In another computer open localhost PHPMyadmin
4. Create new database(name as per you want) Import the database
5. Past project in wamp/www directory
6. open wp-config.php file and change attribute like DB_NAME=(As per you mention at a time of import database) , WP_USER=root, WP_PASSWORD= ""
7. And your project will live